# Creating a C++ Class from a textfile/XML file

Tags: c++, class, parsing, struct, text-files

I basically want to create an internal structure for some datatypes I want to make. These datatypes will hold the bulk of the information in my program (basically a large database, but I want to avoid the hassle of setting one up to use) and will be serialized/unserialized.

But I want to create these classes/structs on the fly, from the layout of a text file/ml file. For instance:

```
container Music
field string name
field largenumber filesize
end container
```

This is a very basic example: in the above, 'container' would be the datatype (class or a struct), 'field' denotes a variable (with string being.. an stl string, and a large number being an unsigned integer or somesuch. Yes, I realise that I want something like a C++ parser (as for a compiler) that checks correct syntax.

I basically want users of my program to create their own datatypes (add a field/remove a field/create their own struct) and then permanently keep that in my program.

(I've already worked out how I can serialize/unserialize while doing this - all I have to do is make sure I also save the last created class/struct text file with the serialized data, so I can recreate the datatypes when I unserialize).

Would anyone know how to go about doing this, or suggest better implementations of my design?

P.S. Obviously this information needs to be created at run-time, not compile-time.

Comment: Can you be more clear? For example, are you having trouble viewing these data as a class? That is, can you write a class that can contain variable number of variable type elements? Or is your problem after that, with serializing it? Or are you generally asking whether there is a better solution?

Comment: Your P.S. is not at all obvious. How will you compile the resulting C++ code at runtime?

Comment: You cannot create new types in a C++ program at run time. You need to create a language for your users to express their types (or reuse an existing language), and implement it in your program. This language need not be similar to C++. There are two different questions here, (1) what kind of language to use and (2) how to implement it. No, make it three. (3) don't you actually need a DBMS?

Comment: When you say "then permanently keep that in my program" i'm assuming you mean definition-wise rather than generating compilable code and throwing it into your address space. I've seen the latter done with Java (a rule engine that was honestly a marvel),  but in C++ I think a dictionary and a suitable variant data type is about the most basic you can do.

Comment: Okay, as a clarification - say you had a nice graphical interface that had rows and columns. Each row would represent one complete 'entry' and each column would be a 'variable' - the entire page would be one table in your DB.

Say you then wanted to add another column (a new variable to your data structure). You also want to keep that column in your outputted data when the program shuts down. 

Would a DBMS be easier to use then?

Comment: what type would the last column be? Can that last column have null values? That's an embarrassing "alter" scenario every programmer tries to avoid

Answer (score 1):

For XML to Object conversion, what you're actually looking at is a part of SOAP. I prefer RapidXML but you can try out other XML parsers to create/read into your object.

With text files, you might have to write your own parser that handles your text file correctly expecting correct types and definitions and then generates the object accordingly.

I agree, dynamically creating an object and populating it with values is not trivial, unless a common interface exists.

As a side-note, since you said you want your users to "CREATE" type dynamically, why not look into a simple scripting language(or make a DSL yourself?)

Comment: I'll look into this if the above option does not work. Thanks for yoru reply!

Answer (score 1):

As you suggest, I would do that by writing an XML parser and the datatype definition would be in the file. This way, parsing is made very easy (use any XML read library). You create the datatype at runtime, all you need is : a class **Container** and a class **Field** where you can store name, type, etc.

You pre-process your XML file, generating a function that would populate some data structure of yours, typically looking like:

```
Field newfield1 (name, type, whatever);
Field newfield2 (name2, type2, whatever2);
...
Container newContainer;
newContainer.addField(newfield1);
newContainer.addField(newfield2);
...
```

Of course, you can organize your code far better than that, but it's just to give the idea. First write down your datatypes as XML, pre-process your XML and generate "run-time" .cpp file to create your dynamic types, you include it in your project and then you can use your types as you need.

To create fields of different types (not known in advance), you can use boost::variant (and generate the typelist from the XML too). And you can even generate one typedef per field to ensure proper types will be used later when you use boost:get<>.

Comment: Excellent! Yes, this sounds like exactly like what I wanted to do - this concept just also seemed like the way a compiler parses it's information, too. Thanks so much!

Comment: After doing some reading, I've found the boost::any class - potentially, I could have a map of boost::any variables, yes? As long as a user specified what the data type was (out of a series of predefined types), it would be easy enough to read the data as XML out of a file and cast it to the right type.

I'm unsure how using variant would work compared to this method. Could you explain?

Comment: Yeah sure, boost::any would also work, depending on how you use it. I like boost::variant better because it provides static checks instead of runtime checks, but it's a matter of taste.
Take a look at this page [Boost comparison page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/variant/misc.html) to decide what suits you best.

Comment: please note as an answer to close the thread if it's ok for you.

Comment: ahah, I mean: click the "tick" next to my post, so that the thread can be marked as "solved".